# Font Awesome icons in Windows 10 Universal Phone not showing Kendo Mobile button

Tags: css, cordova, kendo-ui, windows-phone, windows-10-universal

Kendo is not showing font awesome icons correctly in buttons in a navbar running on cordova on a windows phone.

The icons ares are appearing white as in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be something that kendo is doing for windows phone with k-icon on property of the mobile button using angular in windows 10.

The following code works on all devices except windows 10.

```html
   <kendo-mobile-button k-icon="'trash'"  class="fa"></kendo-mobile-button>
```

The following code which bypasses kendo icons works on all devices tested, android, windows phone, windows and ios.

```html
<kendo-mobile-button><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></kendo-mobile-button>
```

[image]